# Table syntax is messy

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a problem with writing a proper code for my table. Using the table feature in Dreamweaver it does help but when it comes on styling a single column or a row with CSS I see that my code is not properly written. For example if I want to style the first column I have to add class to each tr element. So I need your advice on how my table could be written in a more tidier way.

```
<table width="70%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="qwe3">title</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td class="qwe2">title</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="qwe1">
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="qwe1">
            <td>2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="qwe1">
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="qwe1">
            <td>4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="qwe1">
            <td>5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="qwe1">
            <td>6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="qwe1">
            <td>7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="qwe1">
            <td>8</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="qwe1">
            <td>9</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="qwe1">
            <td>10</td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
        <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td class="qwe2">title</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
        <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td class="qwe2">title</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
        <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td class="qwe2">title</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
        <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td class="qwe2">title</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
        <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td class="qwe2">title</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
        <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td class="qwe2">title</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
        <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td class="qwe2">title</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can see my code live here: http://codepen.io/mariomez/pen/XJqwYy

Ps: I don't want you to write the whole code or something just some tips on what things I should change in my code. :)

Comment: You can use pseudo elements like nth-child or first child...for example for the first column you can use: table tr td:first-child{ background: green;}

Comment: intersting. And how would be the html code for this? just td ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd say write just a single table instead of the tables per column you have right now. You can still keep the big title with red background using `<td colspan="8">title</td>` for that cell.

Once you have this single cleaned table you can use `:first-child` to select only the first `td`s inside a row, excepy maybe the main header. Then unleash your CSS magic.

I included a snippet doing just that [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYGddP).

EDIT: Improved snippet [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jExjrv).

Comment: What about if I want to control the first row of titles (like in your code) in order to have the same style and then to control each column separately?

Comment: I edited the snippet somewhat to have an extra title row [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jExjrv). It demonstrates some of the cool things you can do with the [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-selector. Using that you can control any column separately, or just the odd or even ones. It's pretty powerful, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nested tables! Use colspan and rowspan to achieve desired output.

This is a great starting point to learn table element: [complete guide table element](http://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/).

This is a quick edit of your code: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPeELY).

Notice how I used colspan for the first row:

```
<td colspan="8" class="qwe3">title</td>
```